# Tilde key missing on Arch Linux with XFCE4

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, keyboard-layout

I am running Arch Linux with XFCE4 as desktop environment on a Lenovo T400. The problem is that I am unable to type a tilde ´~´ instead it leads to a ´|´ or ´<´ when using other US layouts. The current keyboard layout is English (US, alternativ International) but I tried any other US layout XFCE has to offer with no solution. So basically I have two keys leading to the same character but no tilde.

Thanks you for any suggestions or solutions!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment yet.  Have you tried setting a 104-key layout instead of 105, or vice-versa?  On 105-key layouts, there is a key between left shift and 'Z'. If I recall correctly, this is the key code generated by what would be the tilde key on a 104-key layout.